# Two seperate .getjson calls returning NAN, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, getjson

Followed a tutorial where I could use two seperate .getjson calls, where the first one will execute to then multiply by data from the next data call, however, it is simply returning NAN as a value, what have I written wrong?

```
$.getJSON( "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/raiblocks/", function( data ) {
  $.getJSON("https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD", function (data2) {
    change['rai-usd-cmc'] = data[0]["price_usd"] * data2["GBP"];
    $(".change-rai-usd-cmc").text(change['rai-usd-cmc']);
    $(".change-rai-usd-cmc").text(parseFloat(change['rai-usd-cmc']).toFixed(2));
    loader(false)
    updateData()
  });
});
```

Trying to multiply data from the first execution with the second getjson call.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: try to use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Comment: I want to avoid using .when as it executes both in parallel (I want the first to execute first), however, I just tried with .when anyways and it simply wouldn't load the numbers. Not sure where I am going wrong with this... It either returns NAN or won't load the numbers.

Comment: just 1 problem with the api, `data2["GBP"]` is not exists in the `data2` object.  That the reason of you getting NAN

Comment: How should I write it then?     data[2]["GBP"]      ?

Comment: shoud be `data[2].rates["GBP"]`. @Chinmoy Samanta show you the answer

Comment: Yes! It is now fixed! Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged your code and saw that "GBP" key is present within data2.rates object not in data2. So the value of data2["GBP"] is undefined. For this reason, it returns NAN as value. So you can rewrite your code with data2.rates["GBP"] instead of data2["GBP"].

Here I attach the code.

```
   $.getJSON( "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/raiblocks/", function( data ) {
  $.getJSON("https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD", function (data2) {
    change['rai-usd-cmc'] = data[0]["price_usd"] * data2.rates["GBP"];
    $(".change-rai-usd-cmc").text(change['rai-usd-cmc']);
    $(".change-rai-usd-cmc").text(parseFloat(change['rai-usd-cmc']).toFixed(2));
    loader(false)
    updateData()
  });
});
```

Comment: Holy shit my man, I have been staring at this problem for an hour and you just fixed it! Thanks a lot. How did you find the problem? So I could learn to fix it myself the next time :)

Comment: You should learn core javascript and how to debug javascript code.